# Converting pointer to 2D array

Tags: c++

I'm calling C++ method from C# code and passing the pointer of first element of a 2D array, and the dimensions of the array to the C++ function:

**C# code**

```
fixed (bool* addressOfMonochromeBoolMatrixOfBitmap = &monochromeBoolMatrixOfBitmap[0, 0]
{             
    NativeGetUniquenessMatrixOfBitmap(addressOfMonochromeBoolMatrixOfBitmap, Width, Height);         
}
```

**C++ code**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void NativeGetUniquenessMatrixOfBitmap ( bool* addressOfMonochromeBoolMatrixOfBitmap, 
    int boolMatrixWidth, int boolMatrixHeight)
{
}
```

In the C++ code I want to cast the bool* pointer to 2D array, in order to access the elements using conventional array syntax: someArray[1][4]. 
I've tried this code:

```
bool (*boolMatrix)[boolMatrixWidth][boolMatrixHeight] = (bool (*)[boolMatrixWidth][boolMatrixHeight])addressOfMonochromeBoolMatrixOfBitmap;
```

But it doesn't compile giving the message "expected constant expression".

Please share any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ 2D array only one array dimension can be from variable, the other one must be constant. So you have to keep the pointer and compute the address of each pixel manually.

And I am affraid you have to swap height and width, i.e. correct is probably [height][width]. If it is so, then height can be variable, but width must be constant. If it isn't constant, you have to keep the `bool*` pointer and compute address of each row like `row = address + width*y` and then you can use `row[x]` to access particular items in the row.

```
//we prepare row pointer to read at position x,y 
bool *row = addressOfMonochromeBoolMatrixOfBitmap + boolMatrixWidth * y;

//example: read from x,y
bool value_at_xy = row[x];

//example: move to next row
row += boolMatrixWidth;
```